# Objective C NSJSONSerialization how to parse sub json

Tags: objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

how to handle a json object with a sub object in the string. Here is an example

[{"_id":"1","Title":"Pineapple","Description":"Dole Pineapple","Icon":"icon.png","Actions":{"ACTION_PHOTO":"coupon.png", "ACTION_LINK":"google.com"}}]

How do you parse the second json "Actions" ?

Answer (score 3):

What you have here is an array of dictionaries (with 1 entry), where one of the entries in the top level dictionary is also a dictionary. So you might have something like this to parse it:

```
NSError *e = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

if (jsonArray) {
    NSDictionary *dictActions;
    for (NSDictionary *dict in jsonArray) {
        dictActions = [dict objectForKey:@"Actions"];
        NSLog(@"The action link is: %@", [dictActions objectForKey@"ACTION_LINK"]);
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", [e localizedDescription]);
}
```